# Sorting and searching on a field which model doesn't have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sorting

I have an HTML table where I show the data from a particular model but I also show a column in the HTML table which doesn't belongs to that model. this column comes after some calculation(In this calculation I use 3-4 more tables). I want to give the sorting and searching functionality on that column. Anyone having idea what is the best way to do that?

Updated:

The main problem is if I provide sorting/searching on that column then I have to fetch all records from database for calculation which will not be good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance solution: just add new field into your table to store your calculation.

Anyway, you can't solve your problem without fetching all your records.

Or you can use JavaScript for searching and sorting, but only if there are not many items.

Comment: Yes... I was thinking the same for new field addition in the table.

Comment: And don't forget to add index to this field

Answer (score 0):

You can sort you model:

```
q_new.sort! { |x, y|
    y.creation_date <=> x.creation_date
}
```

creation_date is a any field or a method of the model.

Comment: ОК. Anyway you must make some calculation and sorting and there is only two places where you can do it - on the client or in the server.  If it is not possible to sort data on client without fetching all the data - you need sort data on server. Add new field to model using which you can get sorted data.

Comment: Yes... I was thinking the same. :) but looking for something better

Answer (score 0):

I would create a virtual resource on the model, which contains the sorter in Ruby-code. Assuming `sum` is your virtual property.

```
def by_sum(options = {})
  @items = self.class.find(options)
  @items.sort! { |a,b| a.sum <=> b.sum }
end
```

In your controller you can call:

```
Item.by_sum({:where => "'foo' = 'bar'"})
```